# How is EKS allocating IP addresses from a secondary CIDR block and what is the correct CIDR range?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Looking to use CNI Custom Networking to get additional IP addresses for EKS. Those IP addresses will be allocated from a secondary CIDR in the VPC.

The AWS documentation has conflicting information and mentions the following:

The first condition is that you add secondary CIDR blocks to a VPC from the 100.64.0.0/10 and 198.19.0.0/16 ranges.
The second condition is that you use CNI custom networking.

I found that not to be true, as I have tested with 10.0.0.0/16 and EKS seems to allocate IPs from that range to the new pods.

The other bit that’s not clear is whether that secondary CIDR will exclusively be used by EKS or I can deploy other resources with IPS from that range? I am guessing it should not be a problem since CNI will first check which IP addresses are available before adding a batch to a queue.

Any experience with the above?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your network setup. 10.0.0.0/16 will work fine, there is no need to add the secondary subnet.

The problem is that in some companies you might only be given 10.0.0.0/24 which an eks cluster will quickly consume all of the ip addresses. AWS recommends utilizing the secondary subnet to prevent customers from running out of ip addresses in their vpc.